# How to calculate Total Rows Size of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I calculate Size of a table.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_INFO
(
EMP_ID INT,
EMP_FNAME VARCHAR (30),
EMP_LNAME VARCHAR (40),
EMP_CNTRY CHAR(40),
EMP_Age tintyint,
EMP_SAL BIGINT
)
```

Comment: dbcc showcontig ('EMPLOYEE_INFO') with tableresults

Comment: For single table you can use-sp_spaceused MyTable

Comment: @Chanukya Sorry, I haven't explained properly. I am looking to find a way to calculate the size manually.

Comment: @rocky09 calculate the size manually means table size? or row size? please explain clearly

Comment: @Chanukya maxmimum Row Size (storage).

Comment: Do you want to calculate the estimated size before you create the table and populate it with data, or you want to check the size of an existing table?

Answer (score 0):

Trying running this query this will give the size of all Table present in DB

```
with SpaceInfo(ObjectId, IndexId, TableName, IndexName
    ,Rows, TotalSpaceMB, UsedSpaceMB)
as
( 
    select  
        t.object_id as [ObjectId]
        ,i.index_id as [IndexId]
        ,s.name + '.' + t.Name as [TableName]
        ,i.name as [Index Name]
        ,sum(p.[Rows]) as [Rows]
        ,sum(au.total_pages) * 8 / 1024 as [Total Space MB]
        ,sum(au.used_pages) * 8 / 1024 as [Used Space MB]
    from    
        sys.tables t with (nolock) join 
            sys.schemas s with (nolock) on 
                s.schema_id = t.schema_id
            join sys.indexes i with (nolock) on 
                t.object_id = i.object_id
            join sys.partitions p with (nolock) on 
                i.object_id = p.object_id and 
                i.index_id = p.index_id
            cross apply
            (
                select 
                    sum(a.total_pages) as total_pages
                    ,sum(a.used_pages) as used_pages
                from sys.allocation_units a with (nolock)
                where p.partition_id = a.container_id 
            ) au
    where   
        i.object_id > 255 AND  t.name not LIKE'%HSt%'
    group by
        t.object_id, i.index_id, s.name, t.name, i.name
)
select 
    ObjectId, IndexId, TableName, IndexName
    ,Rows, TotalSpaceMB, UsedSpaceMB
    ,TotalSpaceMB - UsedSpaceMB as [ReservedSpaceMB]
from 
    SpaceInfo       
order by
    TotalSpaceMB desc
option (recompile)
```